# zend framework login form

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, authentication, validation

I have a log in form that checks the user email and password through the database, if it matches, it allow the user to log in. The problem is it checks the email that matches any password in the database or the password that matches any emails in the database. I want it to check this specific user email to match his password, not matches any password that exists in database.

Here's my controller that I think I did it wrong:

```
$loginForm = new Application_Form_UserLogin();
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('loginForm'))
    {   
        $email_adrress = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email_address');
        $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');

        /************ Login Form ************/
        if ($loginForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($loginForm->getValues()); 
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('email' => $email_adrress, 'hash' => $password));

            if($user) 
            {
                Zend_Session::rememberMe(86400 * 14);
                Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
                $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');
                return;
            } 
            else {
            }               
        }
    }$this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;
```

My form:

```
class Application_Form_UserLogin extends Zend_Form
{
public $email, $password, $submit;

public function init()
{       
    $this->setName('loginForm');        

    $EmailExists = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(
            array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'field' => 'email'
            )
        );

    //$EmailExists->setMessage('Invalid email address, please try again. *');

    $PasswordExists = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(
            array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'field' => 'hash'
            )
        );

    $PasswordExists->setMessage('Invalid password, please try again. *');

    $this->email = $this->createElement('text', 'email_address')
                     ->setLabel('Email')
                     ->addValidator($EmailExists)
                     ->addValidator('EmailAddress')
                     ->setRequired(true);

    $this->password = $this->createElement('text', 'password')
                     ->setLabel('Password')
                     ->addValidator($PasswordExists)
                     ->setRequired(true);


    $this->submitButton = $this->createElement('button', 'btn_login')
                            ->setLabel('Login')
                            ->setAttrib('type', 'submit');

    $this->addElements(array($this->email, $this->password, $this->submit));

    $elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper'
    );
    $this->setElementDecorators($elementDecorators);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't add this login processing as a validator on one of the elements. Instead, I would create an `Zend_Auth` authentication adapter with your User model, email, and password as constructor arguments. Then, in controller, call `Zend_Auth::authenticate($adapter)`.

Something like:

```
class Application_Model_AuthAdapter implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface
{
    protected $userModel;   
    protected $email;
    protected $pass;

    public function __construct($userModel, $email, $pass)
    {
        $this->userModel = $userModel;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user = $this->userModel->getByEmailAndPassword($this->email, $this->pass);
        if ($user){
            return new Zend_Auth_Result(Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS, $user);
        } else {
            return new Zend_Auth_Result(Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_UserLogin();
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {
            $data = $form->getValues();
            $email = $data['email'];
            $pass = $data['pass'];
            $userModel = $this->_helper->model('Users');
            $authAdapter = new Application_Model_AuthAdapter($userModel, $email, $pass);
            $result = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($adapter);
            if ($result->isValid()){
                // $user= $result->getIdentity(). Use it how you like.
                // Redirect someplace
            } else {
                $this->view->error = 'Invalid login';
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

See [Zend_Auth reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html) for more details.

Comment: oh, thanks I will try it out. I was using the Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists to validate the login...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the way you're trying to do it. Is the fetchRowByFields method one you have written yourself? If so, it's difficult to help you without seeing the code.

Have you considered using the mechanism provided by Zend Framework to perform authentication against a database?

The Zend Framework official manual contains a brief tutorial on how to implement authentication:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.multiuser.authentication.html

You use an adapter with the Zend_Auth class to do what you want.

Comment: yea,maybe your true - fetchrowbyfields, it's looking for the whole database instead of that specific one.